# Excel VBA: Max Date in the row including blank cells

Tags: excel, vba

Excel VBA: Code to find Max date in a row which includes blank cells

```
Dim s As Date

s = WorksheetFunction.Max((If IsNotEmpty (CDate(Range("A" & x + 1).Value), CDate(Range("B" & x + 2).Value), CDate(Range("C" & x + 1).Value)))
MsgBox s
```

I have a table in which there are around 8 colums containing dates (ex start date, end date etc). Now for each row, some of the columns are blank. I have to find the max date in each row.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEcPP.png)

Comment: Which row? What is exactly the idea? Try with 2-3 more sentences.

Comment: Did you meant to include something like `If Not IsEmpty.... Then`? Show some sample data if possible to visualize exactly what you are trying.

Comment: I have a table in which there are around 8 colums containing dates (ex start date, end date etc). Now for each row, some of the columns are blank. I have to find the max date in each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you do this :

```
sub tryme()

For i = 1 To 50
    Max_date = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Rows(i))
    if isempty(Max_date) = False then
    MsgBox cDate("The most recent date for row : " & i & "is : " & Max_date)
    end if
Next
end sub
```

Where `i` is your row number; you will have to set your number of rows, or find it with `.Count`

Comment: No, I am getting type mismatch error: For the blank cell "", its showing type mismatch and giving the value #12:00:00#

Answer (score 0):

Hello refer the below code for cell A1 to AA1 contains the date with blank cell also

```
Sub maxdaterow()
Max_date = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("A1:AA1"))
MsgBox Max_date
End Sub
```

below code to find the maximum date in column A, which also contains the blank cells

```
Sub maxdate()
Max_date = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("A"))
MsgBox Max_date
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this and  I am getting Type mismatch 13 error: Value: #12:00:00 AM#

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim i As Long, y As Long
    Dim dDate As Date

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

        'Loop rows 1-10
        For i = 1 To 10
            'Set a default date
            dDate = "1/1/1900"
            'Loop columns from 1-8
            For y = 1 To 8
                If .Cells(i, y).Value <> "" And .Cells(i, y).Value > dDate Then
                    dDate = .Cells(i, y).Value
                End If
            Next y

            Debug.Print "Max date for row " & i & " is date " & dDate

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```